GPU riser "USB" cable compatibility for M.2 and mini PCIe adapters
I mistakenly purchased the wrong PCIe GPU riser (with mini PCIe instead of M.2 adapter on another side) and am curious if it is safe to replace the mini PCIe adapter that was shipped with the riser with the M.2 adapter I purchased separately.
In this case, I also need to change the USB A -> mini USB cable to USB A -> USB A. I know this cable isn’t really a “USB” but just wiring, which is why I’m asking if it’s safe.


This will depend largely on the controllers in the two ends of the adapters. Using a USB cable doesn't necessarily mean that USB is the protocol being used to communicate. See the USB-to-RJ45 adapters some battery backup manufacturers use.
So, it is POSSIBLE you can simply change the cable and connect the other adapter and it'll work, but it is possible it won't.
You will need to check the component documentation or the manufacturer to confirm.
My GUESS is that the odds are greater it WON'T work, because I do not see any controllers on the connector ends you are trying to swap. This means the controller on the PCI board controls all this. This is only a guess though.
